# Cost of large buffer switch vs. small buffer switch

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm creating a tile-based renderer where each tile has a vertex model.  However, from each vertex model only a small portion is rendered in one frame. These subsets change every frame.

What would be the fastest way to render this? I can think of the following options:

1. Make one draw call for every model. Every model is stored in full on the gpu. For every draw call, the full vbo is switched every time. Indices are then used to pick the appropriate small portion for the actual rendering.
2. Make one draw call with one vbo which gets assembled every frame by copying the necessary (small) subset of all the other vbos (the data is copied within vram).
3. Make one draw call with one vbo, but the vbo is recreated every frame with the (small) subset from CPU data using glBufferData.

Which do you think is fastest, or can you think of something faster?

One deciding factor is obviously if switching between larger VBOs is more expensive than switching between smaller VBOs.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to make a lot of drawcalls. In OpenGL,you will be CPU bound by this method, so it is better to batch a lot of models.

Actually, I would go for this method. All static geometry is inside one and only one VBO and one VAO. It does not mean that you only have "one draw call". However, you should use glMultiDraw*Indirect.
The idea burried that is you have to use compute shaders to perform culling on GPU, and use something like GL_INDIRECT_PARAMETERS extensions with your multi indirect draw call.
[Indirect Drawing](http://cpp-rendering.io/indirect-rendering/)

For all dynamic geometry, you can use a persistent buffer.

To answer your question about changing vao/vbo. Change VAO, or use glBindVertexBuffer should not make a big overhead.

But you should profile it, it can depends on your driver / hardware :)